# video.js grunt Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gruntjs, video.js

When i run the command  `grunt dev` or `grunt build` its open the grunt.js in the file editor and does'nt run the grunt server and when i copy all the code in `gruntfile.js` then its resturn the errors of syntex.

[image: error image]

> > SyntaxError: D:\Projects\videojs\video.js\Gruntfile.js:6
> >
> > let _ = require('lodash-compat');
> >
> > Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download stable version of video.js. Hope it will help